# Predicting a new document

Tags: python, prediction, nlp, tfidf

I have a document, (purchase agreement) of approx. 100 pages. This document is sent from buyer to seller several times, and each time there is a negotiation. Negotiation could be anything.

---

For eg. Change in the amount of Insurance cover, or the definition of any term could be changed.
To be more specific, buyer claims the loss covered to be 10,000 dollars (Version 1 of agreement). Seller changes the agreement to cover a loss of $5,000  (Version 2). This way there is a change in the original document.

---

QUESTION: Is there any way by which I can predict what could be the negotiation? Can I use NLP or tf-idf to track the common changes that occurs in the document and then predict it on the new document?